# Constraint causing UIView to not size consistently

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I'm experiencing some trouble with constraints I'm using to create spacing between `UIButtons`. I have three buttons spaced out horizontally with equal spacing between each button. I'm using horizontal spacing constraints between each button. For the "My Tracks" button, it has a leading constraint to the container. For the "Community" button, it has a trailing constraint to the superview and the relation is "less than or equal to".

When a button is selected, a line is drawn beneath it based on the frame width of the button. As you can see, the "My Tracks" line is way wider than the other buttons. This only occurs on + sized phones. Does not occur on iPhone X. What constraint do you think could be causing this?

8+
[image]

[image]

[image]

X
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it's the width of the button, you probably want the size of the text in the text label in the button

Comment: @FredFaust ya, but why is the button width wider on only the + phones? And why is only one button getting wider?

Comment: @FredFaust I also need the button frame to get the origin of where the line should begin.

Comment: Looks like the issue goes away when I delete the trailing constraint on the community button, but then I get a warning saying that the trailing constraint is missing and may cause overlap

Comment: You could try setting the priority of the trailing constraint to 750.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be caused by the relation "less than or equal to".

Is there any reason that you don't want them to be equal widths?

Else you could set the buttons to have equal widths and heights, it'll look consistent across all devices.

Comment: Ya it was definitely the trailing constraint on the Community button. Changing it to "greater than or equal to" worked. I tried setting equal widths but I get that new localization clipping warning.